# Can you "feel dubious" about something?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

My general feeling is that "dubious" should be used to describe "a dubious wastrel" or "a dubious abandoned castle drawbridge" — instead of "I felt dubious towards that wastrel" or "The bridge caused me to feel dubious."

I think the latter examples are acceptable, but my feeling was that it was a slight misusage of the word — but I don't know why I feel this way.

Thus, you might re-phrase "I'm feeling dubious that aliens are why all our chocolate was eaten" as "the defense that aliens ate all our chocolate seemed dubious."

Is this based in anything? Am I making up this distinction? I know that suspicious (now?) has that double, but distinct (!), usage where you can be suspicious of someone, or they can be "a suspicious character" — but I don't feel the same about dubious.

Comment: Rather than 'I'm feeling dubious', why not say simply 'I doubt'? Any dictionary will tell you that _dubious_ can mean both 'feeling doubtful' and 'untrustworthy'.

Answer (score 2):

***Dubious*** can mean

> thought not to be completely true or not able to be trusted:
>
> - These claims are ***dubious*** and not scientifically proven.
> - He has been associated with some ***dubious*** characters.

but it also has the meaning you need:

> feeling doubt or not feeling certain:
> I'm ***dubious*** about his promises to change his ways.([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dubious))

Note, however, that the most common usage is *to **be** dubious **about** something* (not *feel dubious that*, of which [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feels%20dubious%20that%2Cam%20dubious%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is unable to find instances).

Most dictionaries will give you examples with *be dubious about*:

> - I ***was** **dubious** **about*** the plan. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dubious))
> - My parents ***were dubious about*** it at first but we soon convinced them. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dubious))
> - I ***was*** pretty ***dubious about*** the whole idea. ([OxfordL](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/dubious))

So your could say

> I'm dubious about aliens having eaten all our chocolate.

However, rather than complicating things in this way just to stick to *dubious*, I do agree with @KateB that it is much more common and more idiomatic to say:

> I ***doubt*** that aliens (are the ones who) ate all our chocolate.

Comment: Both senses are quite old; [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dubious) says: 1540s, "puzzling, occasioning doubt or uncertainty;" 1630s, "doubtful, hesitating in opinion;" So it's not even a case of one meaning being much more recent than the other.

Comment: A balanced / well weighted answer. A pity OP didn't add a single dictionary's list of senses, but the balancing/weighting would still be needed in an 'answer'.

Answer (score 0):

Within my own fiction writing I find I lean more towards using "I felt doubtful towards that person" rather than dubious. Then when it comes to buildings, larger areas and abstract terms I would predominately use dubious. For example "The dubious alleyway beckoned me for reasons unknown."